# Asymptotic density of twin primes gives wrong result in Mathematica

Tags: prime-numbers

One can compute the amount of twin primes below a positive integer $n$ by using the Mathematica command ([taken from OEIS A001097](https://oeis.org/A001097)):

```
Length[Select[Prime[Range[n]], PrimeQ[# + 2] &]]
```

The twin prime conjecture states that this value should approach $1.320323632\ldots\times\int_2^n \frac{dt}{\log^2 t}$. So I tried using

```
N[Integrate[Log[t]^(-2),{t,2,n}]]*1.320323632
```

However, I got vastly different results than I expected. For instance, for $n=1000$ and $n=10000$ I get, respectively, $45.8\ldots$ and $214.21\ldots$, while the real values are $174$ and $1270$. Obviously, there is something wrong with the Mathematica command above. But what is it?

Comment: You've posted this in a blog already?  http://mathematics.filegala.com/2018/09/14/asymptotic-density-of-twin-primes-gives-wrong-result-in-mathematica/

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the exact link at OEIS.

Comment: @JimB No, that looks like someone took my post and copy-pasted it somewhere... That is highly alarming.

Comment: The "real values" are 35 and 205 and @AnxonPues gives you the right answer.  The number of "pairs" under `n` might be better given as `(Length[Select[
     Prime[Range[n]], (PrimeQ[# - 2] || PrimeQ[# + 2]) && # <= n & ]] + 1)/2`.  It is necessary to add in the condition `# <= n`.

Comment: I agree.  That is more than highly alarming.

Comment: @JimB Posted on Meta: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29098/it-looks-like-this-website-is-copying-mathematica-se-questions-automatically

Comment: @JimB Why not simply `(Length[Select[ Prime[Range[n]], (PrimeQ[# + 2]) && # <= n & ]] + 1)`?

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-should-i-do

Comment: I think you want `p2[n_] := Length[Select[Prime[Range[PrimePi[n]]], PrimeQ[# + 2] &]]` to get the upper bound correct.

Comment: @PreservedFruit.  Yes, your function better.  I just wanted to add in the `# < = n` part to your original equation as the item that gives the result you desired.

Comment: The answers to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179114/does-mathematica-have-a-twin-prime-equivalent-of-primepi) question give further insight and faster methods to count twin primes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This I think fails because `Prime[Range[n]]` gives the first `n` primes not the primes below `n`.
For this purpose, there might be another function, read help and you will find.

Comment: The code I write in my question is the one on the OEIS, to calculate the twin primes under a positive integer $n$. I doubt it is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Anxon Pués is absolutely right. What you compute is $\pi_2(p(n))$, so the integral has also to run from $2$ to $\pi_2(p(n))$:

```
ClearAll[n];
f[n_] := Rest[Accumulate[Subtract[1, Unitize[Differences[Prime[Range[n]]] - 2]]]];
g[n_] = Integrate[Log[t]^(-2), {t, 2, n}, Assumptions -> n >= 2];
n = 100000
ListLinePlot[1.320323632 g@N[Prime[Range[2, n - 1]]]/f[n], 
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesLabel -> {"p[n]", "Ratio"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Then the code in the OEIS is wrong?

Comment: That depends on what the programs are suppose to do. A there is no such program description on `OEIS`. I guess they are just meant to generate the first couple of elements of the sequence, not the function $\pi_2(n)$.

Comment: Alternatively, could you please help me fix it so that it returns $\pi_2(n)$?

Comment: See function `f` in my post: `f[n]` returns the list of $\pi_2(2),\pi_2(3), \dotsc,\pi_2(n)$. That's a bit more efficient than searching for the first few twins over and over again. Moreover, it avoids performing prime tests.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Comment: Ah, wait: `f[n]` returns the sequence $\pi_2(p(2)),\pi_2(p(3)),\dotsc, \pi_2(p(n))$ where $p(n)$ is the $n$-th prime. The difference is that I evaluate the integral in `g(n)` also from $2$ to $p(n)$.

Comment: You're welcome.